# Doctrine DQL conditional query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to build a dynamic query with Doctrine's query builder. Let's say I'd also like to optionally select an end time in the following (only if one was entered). How would I add this conditionally to the statement?

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('m')
        ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'm')
        ->where("m.start > '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start)) . "'")
        ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
// first, create the query builder
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('m')
    ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'm')
;

// add the default condition
$conditions = array(
    $qb->expr()->gt('m.start', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($start)));
);

// put your condition here
if (isset($end)) {
    $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->lt('m.end', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($end)));
}

// convert the conditions to an AND clause
$conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb, 'andX'), $conditions);

// add the WHERE clause
$qb->where($conditions);

// get the query
$query = $qb->getQuery();
```

Comment: This works. Thanks! However, it should be: $conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(), 'andx'), $conditions);