# Building dynamic Doctrine query

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to build filter for my database. Based on values of several form inputs I need to construct appropriate query. This is the code:

```
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('c.title')
            ->from('Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences', 'c');         
    $conditions=array(
        $qb->expr()->gt('c.title',$enquiry->getNaziv()) );//First condition 

    if ($enquiry->getKontakt()!=null) {
         $conditions[] = $qb->expr()->lt('c.contactemail',$enquiry->getKontakt())}//Adding second, optional condition

    $conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb, 'andX'), $conditions);
    $qb->where($conditions);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
```

When I run this I get folowing exception:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder' does not have a method 'andX'

*EDIT After call_user_func_array() modification I get following error:

> QueryException: SELECT c.title FROM Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences c WHERE c.title > ITRO AND c.contactemail < somemail@yahoo.com

Obviously, query is not formatted quite right. I was following this post:[Doctrine DQL conditional query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283700/doctrine-dql-conditional-query)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built dynamic query with the following code:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

            $naziv = $enquiry->getNaziv();
            $drzava=$enquiry->getDrzava();
            $oblast=$enquiry->getOblast();
            $grad=$enquiry->getGrad();
            $provincija=$enquiry->getProvincija();
            $kontakt=$enquiry->getKontakt();
            $sajt=$enquiry->getSajt();

            $testquery = "SELECT c.title FROM Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences c JOIN c.topicid t JOIN c.locationid l JOIN l.stateid s WHERE c.lh = :lh";
            $testparam ['lh'] = $lh;

            if ($kontakt != '') {
                    $testquery .= " and c.contactemail = :kontakt";
                    $testparam['kontakt'] = $kontakt;
            }
            if ($drzava != '') {
                    $testquery .= " and s.name = :drzava";
                    $testparam['drzava'] = $drzava;
            }

            if ($provincija != '') {
                    $testquery .= " and l.province = :provincija";
                    $testparam['provincija'] = $provincija;
            }

             if ($grad != '') {
                    $testquery .= " and l.city = :grad";
                    $testparam['grad'] = $grad;
            }

             if ($sajt != '') {
                    $testquery .= " and c.siteurl = :sajt";
                    $testparam['sajt'] = $sajt;
            }

             if ($oblast != '') {
                    $testquery .= " and t.name = :oblast";
                    $testparam['oblast'] = $oblast;
            }

            $query = $em->createQuery($testquery)->setParameters($testparam);
            $result = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. andx is all lowercase
2. andx is a function of expr(), not of query builder:

   $conditions = call_user_func_array(array($qb->expr(), 'andx'), $conditions);

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select('c')
            ->from('Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences', 'c');
```

Use doctrine (as an ORM) to select the entire object.  You can still where clause on the fields.  Also gt and lt search on strings are not really proper sql practice.  They will likely produce odd results with improper letter case.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried with entire object and I'm getting the same error. If this is not the way, what is common practice when dealing with dynamic queries in Doctrine?

Comment: We need a better idea of what you hope to accomplish with c.contactemail < somemail@yahoo.com (and c.title > ITRO) before we can really answer.

Comment: This is just simple example that needs to be scaled. For each form input filled by user I need to add additional where condition. If some of the inputs is left blank there is no need for query appendage... You get the point.

Answer (score 0):

Years later here it is how I do it:

```
    if (array_key_exists('phone', $filters)) {
        $qb->andWhere('p.phone LIKE :phone')
        ->setParameter(':phone', '%' . $filters['phone'] . '%');
    }
```

Hope this helps to someone