# Is it possible to use a conditional statement in my symfony dql repository class? IF YES HOW?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I HAVE THIS IN MY CONTROLLER.

```
         $dql =  $Product->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->select('p')
            ->from('AppBundle:Product','p')
            ->join('p.group', 'g')
            ->join('g.category', 'c')
            ->join('c.department', 'd')
            ->where('d = :department');



           if ($brand){
            ->andWhere('p.brand < :brand')
        }
        if ($gender){
           ->andWhere('p.gender >= :gender')
        }
        ->setParameter('department', $id)
            ->setParameter('brand', $brand)
            ->setParameter('gender', $gender)
```

is it possible to have something like this in my repository class?

Comment: See if this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283700/doctrine-dql-conditional-query

Comment: `if ($brand) { $dql->andWhere('p.brand < :brand')->setParameter('brand', $brand); }`